# boto3 instance.private_dns_name still returns despite disabling VPC DNS hostnames

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC with a disabled DNS Hostnames  and then launching a new Instance onto this VPC but every time I check the instance.private_dns_name using boto3, it always returns a name. Should this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option gives you a public DNS name, not the Private one. See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support).

If both options are turned off, then the public DNS is not given to the instances and also Amazon DNS server will not resolve the private DNS hostnames. But still, the private DNS name is given.

> **enableDnsHostnames**
>
> Indicates whether instances with public IP addresses get corresponding public DNS hostnames.
>
> If this attribute is true, instances in the *VPC get public DNS hostnames*, but only if the enableDnsSupport attribute is also set to true.
>
> **enableDnsSupport**
>
> Indicates whether the DNS resolution is supported.
>
> If this attribute is false, the Amazon-provided DNS server that resolves public DNS hostnames to IP addresses is not enabled.
>
> If this attribute is true, queries to the Amazon provided DNS server at the 169.254.169.253 IP address, or the reserved IP address at the base of the VPC IPv4 network range plus two will succeed. For more information, see Amazon DNS Server.

You can turn off the private DNS name by modifying the DHCP option set as mentioned the other [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html).